# Adobe acrobat not printing "there were no pages selected to print"

Tags: printing, adobe-acrobat

I am constantnly getting the error message "there were no pages selected to print" with acrobat v9 on XP. Anyone know how to get rid of this problem - other than a re-install?

Comment: "other than a re-install", do you mean you already tried it, and it didn't solve the problem, or that you don't want or can't do that?

Comment: i downloaded the latest version of adobe and finally, could print the document..!!

Comment: I faced the same issue.

Try to open the pdf file using any browser say Google Chrome or Firefox using path like file://C:/Documents/my-pdf-file.pdf.

Then try to print.

The issue is with signatures or security in pdf document, which restrict PDF viewer to print the document.

Answer (score 3):

Stopping & restarting the **Print Spooler** local windows service is also a possible solution. 
Works for me on Windows7 x64.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it to print by changing the printer configuration (a network printer). I changed to using a network name (rather than IP address) for the printer mapping and it installed a printer driver for this "new" printer onto the local xp box - all then worked ok. Strange, as I have previously printed from acrobat fine using the IP address mapping. So either changing to the network name or the fact that the printer driver was reinstalled, cured the problem.  BTW: I have also seen something similar happen on a printer at work (again on a system that had worked fine previously).

Answer (score 1):

Same here. I had to reathenticate to the network outside of Acrobat and then when I returned to Acrobat I was able to send the print job to the network printer successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Foxit Viewer may also be of help here. It's much lighter-weight (and with fewer security issues) than Adobe Reader.